# Insert image in JFX Label in between two strings

Tags: javafx

How to insert an image in JFX Label but in between two Strings.Example : Text of JFX Label should be , "text 1  any text 2".
Is this possible dynamically  ???

Comment: If JFX = JavaFX, then it is not possible. Your best option would be two use 2 labels or create a custom control.

Comment: Thanks ItachiUchiha,  Can you pleas guide how to create Custom control ?

Comment: Why not just use a `HBox`? You could have two labels (one with text and a graphic, one with just text), or three labels (text, graphic, text, respectively), or two labels with an `ImageView` between them, or....

Comment: ... or a [TextFlow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html).